# MySQL ISAM search optimization

Tags: mysql, aggregate, mysql-5.7, mysql5

I have a table with 1,019,502 records and a specific query that is taking 1.6 seconds to run. I would like to reduce the run time if possible.

The table is INNODB on MySQL 5.7 (on Ubuntu):

```
mysql> describe summary_data;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| propId       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| elemType     | varchar(50)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sku          | varchar(100)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| family       | varchar(100)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subcategory  | varchar(100)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| category     | varchar(100)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| details      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| merchSales   | float(12,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| orders       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| quantity     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| margin       | float(12,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| grossSales   | float(12,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| discount     | float(12,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| shipping     | float(12,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tax          | float(12,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createDate   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date         | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dateType     | varchar(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The query is as follows:

```
SET @propId = 1,
@from = '2016-01-01',
@to = '2016-12-31',
@elemType = 'sku',
@sku = NULL,
@family = NULL,
@subcategory = NULL,
@category = NULL;

SELECT SUM(ifnull(merchSales,0)+ifnull(discount,0)) as totalSales
,SUM(ifnull(merchSales,0)) as merchSales
,SUM(ifnull(orders,0)) as orders
,SUM(ifnull(quantity,0)) as quantity
,sum(ifnull(grossSales,0)) as grossSales
,sum(ifnull(discount,0))*(-1) as discount
,sum(ifnull(shipping,0)) as shipping
,elemType
,sku
,family
,category
,subcategory
,details
,SUM(ifnull(margin,0)) as margin
,sum(ifnull(margin,0)) / sum(ifnull(merchSales,0))*100 as marginPerc
,SUM(ifnull(grossSales,0))/SUM(ifnull(orders,0)) as avgOrderVal
,sum(ifnull(merchSales,0)+ifnull(discount,0))/sum(ifnull(margin,0))*100 as marginPercTotal
FROM summary_data
WHERE propId = @propId
AND dateType = 'day'
AND elemType = @elemType
AND (@sku IS NULL OR sku = @sku)
AND (@family IS NULL OR family = @family)
AND (@subcategory IS NULL OR subcategory = @subcategory)
AND (@category IS NULL OR category = @category)
GROUP BY category,subcategory,family,sku
ORDER BY merchSales DESC;
```

The index used by the query:

```
mysql> show indexes from summary_data;
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | propId      | A         |         218 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | elemType    | A         |        1529 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | category    | A         |        5528 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            4 | subcategory | A         |       11198 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            5 | family      | A         |       15678 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            6 | sku         | A         |       17470 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            7 | dateType    | A         |       17470 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| summary_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            8 | date        | A         |      985490 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

The query uses about 115,000 of the 1,019,502 records. The results return 2106 aggregated rows.

Any advice would be appreciated!

***** EDIT *****

Adding Explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys                    | key     | key_len | ref         | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | summary_data | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,propId_4,propId_5,propId | PRIMARY | 156     | const,const | 492745 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I could be wrong, as I haven't done any research, but I believe the sum of a null value is 0 by default.

Comment: What does the explain output say? Please add it (as text) to your question. (suggest you always do this for optimizations)

Comment: and following from @jhpratt SUM() ignores NULLs so you could avoid running IFNULL() on every row by reversing the function sequence e.g. IFNULL(SUM(column),0)

Comment: @Used_By_Already I added the explain statement.

Comment: @jhpratt I removed the ifnull() statements which shaved 0.02 seconds off the processing time. TY for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, it's something! IMO 1.6 isn't bad for what you're doing. *Many* sums on over a million rows is going to take time.

Comment: @jhpratt yeah - in itself it's not bad. But when we have to run the query 2 times on the same page to produce year-over-year comparisons it can make the page take >3 secs to process just the queries on the page. >3 secs is an eternity in the UIX world :( I even have a client requirement that will require the query to be run 6 times on a single page. Somehow Google Analytics can run to-the-day year-over-year comparisons on the fly to produce listings in a snappy fashion, I figure there have to be improvements I can make.

Comment: Another thing I see after looking more into it is you are summing some columns multiple times. You can store this in a variable or (I think) reference the column you just selected.

Answer (score 0):

The only constant part of your where clause involves:

```
WHERE propId = @propId
AND dateType = 'day'
AND elemType = @elemType
```

So there *MIGHT* be some advantage in declaring a non-unique composite index involving those 3 fields propid, elemtype, datetype *(nb: I'm not confident I can specify the order of those columns in such an index, it may require some experimmentation)* and I would try an explain after defining such an index but make sure these variables remain NULL while trialing this:

```
@sku = NULL,
@family = NULL,
@subcategory = NULL,
@category = NULL
```

IF there is any improvement from that composite index, now try making any one of those 4 variables non-null. What is the impact on your explain plan? You MIGHT then find that you need non-unique indexes on each of those columns individually to help support the variability of your where clause.

i.e. as you change the variables the explain plan will also vary.

*But: at ~1.6 seconds from >1million rows you are entering into the realm of diminishing returns.*

Comment: TY @Used_By_Already. I'm going to play around with your suggestions today. Also I'd like to add one more constant to my where clause: date range. There will always be a data > and date < in the where clause. If this changes your recommendations please let me know.

Comment: I tried several iterations of composite index variations, including your specific recommendation and all increased the search time. I did find that adjusting the PRIMARY KEY to prioritize the datetype/date columns before the cat/subcat/family/sku AND including the selected columns had a significant impact. This primary key reduced the search time to 0.8s: add primary key(propId,elemType,dateType,date,category,subcategory,family,sku,merchSales,grossSales,quantity,orders,shipping,tax,details). Still looking for improvements - thanks for the help!

Comment: This is good news and also seens to me you have aquired the skill to use and leverage explain output. Well done.